# Where are files stored when running ng serve?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I run `ng serve`, where are the files generated and stored?  I need to troubleshoot why the app works with `ng serve` but not for production build.

Forgot to mention that I'm using webpack version of angular-cli.

Comment: Dist folder is created n all files used for serve stored there

Comment: Are you using the `@webpack` version of the CLI?

Comment: @MithunPattankar Dist folder is only created for ng build.  I don't see it when I run ng serve.

Comment: @Brocco yes, I'm using webpack version.

Comment: Considering starting a project with Angular-CLI. Did this work out for you? Were you able to debug?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

With the webpack version the output isn't written to disk. Webpack manages that all in memory and serves it to the browser using the `webpack-dev-server`.

If you'd like to view the dev output, you will need to run `ng build` and then look into the `dist` directory

Comment: I think running `ng serve` serves some HTML files directly from my project folder because I notice that `ng build` doesn't include those HTML files I need in the dist folder.  Those HTML files are my imports for the Polymer components.  It works fine with `ng serve`.

Comment: Can I customize `ng serve` command? I mean I want to run some bash commands say `node abc.js` before every `ng serve` is it possible?

Comment: can anyone explain which memory? Like there is a tons of memories. Is it RAM? Is it GPU cache? Is it disk memory? If I have 1G Ram memory, how does it manage? Excuse me please, I am this dumb. Help!

Comment: @AdamBajger when anyone says "memory" it's often RAM, specially in programming.

Comment: @WileyMarques apparently it's virtual address space: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20686868/2063755

Answer (score 3):

If your requirement is to have the files on the disk while developing, then use

`ng build --configuration development --watch`

which will keep and eye out for changes. This will enable you to develop angular by another hosting server (like apache OR your backend application). Note: all configuration related to `--configuration development` will be available in `build` section in `angular.json` file which can be edited as convenient