# Where does `ng serve` output files to?

Tags: angular-cli

`ng serve` is not building to the path that I have set in my angular-cli.json in `apps[0].outDir`.

`ng build` works correctly and builds to the path that I have specified.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where are files stored when running ng serve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39256780/where-are-files-stored-when-running-ng-serve)

Comment: Perhaps is a duplicate... but it seems that when folks google this question the wording here somehow serves them better, this has 4x the views. What's the standard way of resolving that?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

It's correct that `ng serve` builds in memory.

Angular CLI does not have support for running a server and writing to disk at the same time.

If you are using your own server, etc., you can use `ng build --watch`, which will watch files just like `ng serve`, but will write them to disk, and will not run a server.

Check this official documentation on how to serve files from disk:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-disk-serve

Comment: Thanks for above. Would ng build concatenate and minify files? I ideally during development, I wouldn't want it to. We build on "dev containers" and don't need to spin up a development server.

Comment: It works in dev mode by default, which doesn't do minification / concatenation etc. When you are ready to ship, you run `ng build -prod` to get the optimized build. It does not spin a server either way. At work I host the site in IIS and develop using `ng build --watch`.

Comment: Is there any way I can get the browser to auto-refresh every time the build is done, like `ng serve` does?

Comment: Nothing built into the CLI itself does that, because no server to call the browser to trigger the refresh.

Comment: Can I customize `ng serve` command? I mean I want to run some bash commands say `node abc.js` before every `ng serve` is it possible?

Comment: There might be something you can do in the `architect/serve` part of the `angular.json` file, but usually when people want to do that they make it an npm script in `package.json` and add what they want before `ng serve` and call this script instead of calling `ng serve` directly.

Comment: @iMe I found something on the official angular pages that might be of interest for your live build + serve question: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#building-and-serving-from-disk

Answer (score 17):

Output is not written to disk when using ng serve. Everything will be kept in memory.
Source:
[Where are files stored when running ng serve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39256780/where-are-files-stored-when-running-ng-serve)

Comment: Thanks Steven!  I missed that question.