# Where does Angular CLI store CSS using LESS as style?

Tags: css, angular, less, angular-cli

Where does Angular CLI store the transpiled CSS files, in a project created with:

```
ng new appname --style less
```

when the project is served using

```
ng serve
```

Comment: What do you mean? If you `ng build` everything is stored in `/dist` (or other directory of your choice), if you `ng serve` it's held in-memory. After you've initially generated the project there are no transpiled files. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: The second you wrote: doing `ng serve` I could not see the resulting css files and I was wondering why. I come from Visual Studio where after building the project I had all the resulting css files in the project folder. From your comment I assume this is similar to what `ng build` does. Thank you.

Comment: Then see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/40087369/3001761