# How do I create something that works like a logging control in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, nstextview

I'm after something like the application output window in Visual Studio, like so:
[image]

I'd like to be able to:

1. bind to an `ObservableCollection` of strings
2. select and copy text (as shown in the screenshot above)

At present this is for a Mac app, although iOS may follow later.

I've tried these:

`Editor` - Problem is it only exposes a `Text` property that I can bind to and not a collection. Sooner or later, the maximum string length will be reached.

`ListView` with `Label` for `ViewCell` - Problem is text from a `Label` is not selectable, let alone having multiple lines (bound collection items) selectable.

Using a custom renderer for Mac that makes use of `NSTextView` and appending to `textStorage` every time a new item is added, but again, there’s a limit to how much you can add to `textStorage`.

I'm open to using third-party tools such as Syncfusion, if that makes it easier.

Comment: That's possible by using `NSTextView` to achieve that . Need to do some custom method to deal with list data and new line display 。

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Thanks. Would it be worthwhile me just changing the question to be simply how to achieve this using `NSTextView` in that case?

Comment: Yes , that's worthwhile .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom a method to deal with list data to combine them into a newline string :

```
public string formatstring(NSArray objects)
{
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for(nuint i=0;i< objects.Count; i++)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append(objects.GetItem<NSString>(i) +"\n");
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Then used in **NSTextView** as follow :

```
string[] items = new string[] {"111111" , "222222" , "333333" , "444444" , "555555" };
NSArray array = NSArray.FromStrings(items);
NSTextView textView = new NSTextView(new CGRect(100,160,200,100));
textView.BackgroundColor = NSColor.Gray;
textView.Value = formatstring(array);
View.AddSubview(textView);
```

The effect :

[image]

Comment: Cool, thanks, that looks promising. I’ll give it a try. One question though - is there a limit on how big the StringBuilder can get? We are talking days worth of console logs. Visual Studio for Mac’s application output panel seems to handle it.

Comment: @AjLearning About limit should exist, not knowing too much about that , you can have a look at this discussion : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20672920/maxcapacity-of-stringbuilder .No matter whether contains the limit of StringBuilder , I think better make the output logs better to load batch display on NSTextView.

Comment: Thanks, I had a look. Batch display is precisely where I’m stuck at. I’d like to be able to display in batches, but seems like there are several variables involved: how many items to load either direction of vertical scroll position, panel height vs font size, maintaining position of lines currently in view, etc. Which is why I thought it would be better to ask a new, NSTextView specific question. If you think the items I’ve mentioned will be of significance, then I’m happy to accept this answer and move onto a new question.

Comment: What I’d really like to know is how it’s implemented in Visual Studio for Mac.

Comment: @AjLearning Got it ,  it will be of significance , you can move onto a new question . Thanks for marking :-)